# Surly disc trucker 26 frame size

Tags: bike-fit

I am 176 cm height (with 85 cm inseam). What will be my frame size for Surly disc trucker 26? Will size 56cm fit or be too big? I cannot find a size for this model. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Surly itself gives some recommendations on the bike fit: https://surlybikes.com/info_hole/spew/spew_bike_fit . The 56 cm frame size might be too big for you, or it might be OK, depending not only on your body dimensions, but on your riding preferences.

Comment: I want to build an touring bike to travel long distances. I would like to avoid pain in my hands or numb wrists so I would have to have a more straight position.

Comment: The best solution is for you to get a leg over a trucker and see how it feels for you.  While seatposts can be extended, and dropped to a point, and stems can be anything from 0 to 200mm, there's a sweet-spot in having a frame size that suits you.    Do you ride a bike at the moment?  What shape/style and what frame size is that ?

Comment: I am currently riding a mtb bike that is 19 inches in size. Unfortunately, the frame I mean is only available in the internet shop. I asked the retailer which size to choose with my dimensions - I got the answer - L size. I can't find information how much it is in cm.

Comment: What size did you end up going with?

Comment: @Adrian It has been over a year - can you give any update on your progress ?